# Validation rule on percentage field

Tags: validation, validation-rule

How would you do implement validation rule which prevents users from entering a decimal into a percentage field.  For example, if the user enters `0.5  or .07`, give error. So the user can enter greater than 1 or equal.
I have tried
I have created the following validations and my validations is active:

```
OR( discount_percentage__c >= 1.0 )
```

When I enter `0.5` I was able to save the record the expectation is that it should throw an error because its not greater or equal to 1

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that `Percents` are stored as follows: `0.10 means 10` percent.
so I end-up re-writing the validation rule like this:

```
discount_percentage__c < 0.01
```

Hope this will help other.

Answer (score 0):

Validation Rules are triggered when the condition evaluates to `TRUE`. Your condition is backwards: it is `TRUE` for values *greater than* 1.0, rather than your desired less than..

Additionally, the `OR()` does nothing at all here, because you have only one criterion. You can remove it.

Comment: I got it about the `or` but I'm not sure what you trying to say, you saying I should have something like this `discount_percentage__c <= 1.0 `

Comment: @NickKahn Exactly. When the validation rule is TRUE, it causes an error.

Comment: I tried `<= 1.0` and still does not work this time it fails all the time even though I have 1.0 or 2.0 still get the validations error, if I enter the value 1.0 it should not fire the validation rule but in my case it fires all the time